# Building with theos on OS X with libc++: undefined symbols for std::allocator and std::basic_string

Tags: c++, macos, clang, theos, libc++

This is a problem I've been having for over a year that I continue to return to every so often, and it's the main reason I have always been scared away from using theos(for building iOS tweaks). Today I have decided to try again, and I have made a test theos project once more and attempted to build it with 'make'. This is the sample code I'm attempting to build:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

struct Mine
{
    std::string nice;

    Mine(std::string p)
    {
        nice = p;
    }

    virtual void poop()
    {
        printf("%s", this->nice.c_str());
    }
};

int main()
{
    Mine* mine = new Mine("nice");
    mine->poop();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the basic Makefile I'm using to build this in theos:
    GO_EASY_ON_ME=1
    messages=yes

```
include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = tweak_test
tweak_test_CXXFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11
tweak_test_LDFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11
tweak_test_FILES = main.cpp

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

Notice that I am in fact specifying that I would like to use the libc++ STL when building (I must use libc++ for the tweak I am building since the app that I am hooking uses it, and there would be runtime conflicts if they were different, namely due to libc++'s short string optimization feature, which makes its strings use up 24 bytes rather than 8 on libstdc++, among other things).

No matter what I do, however, I always get linker errors with std::string related functions. This is the output from theos, with verbose turned on so that execution is printed:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Air:tweak_test ryan$ make
> Making all for tweak tweak_test…
set -o pipefail; (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile --no-print-directory --no-keep-going \
        internal-library-compile \
        _THEOS_CURRENT_TYPE=tweak THEOS_CURRENT_INSTANCE=tweak_test _THEOS_CURRENT_OPERATION=compile \
        THEOS_BUILD_DIR="." _THEOS_MAKE_PARALLEL=yes)
set -o pipefail; (mkdir -p /Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/)
(printf "\e[0;3%im==> \e[1;39m%s…\e[m\n" 2 "Compiling main.cpp (armv7)"); set -o pipefail; (xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang++ -x c++ -c -I/opt/theos/include -include /opt/theos/Prefix.pch -DTARGET_IPHONE=1 -O0 -Wall  -isysroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=__IPHONE_6_0 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0  -fmodules -fcxx-modules -fmodule-name=tweak_test -fbuild-session-file=/Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/build_session -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session   -I/opt/theos/vendor/include -I/opt/theos/include/_fallback -DDEBUG -ggdb -O0  -DTHEOS_INSTANCE_NAME="\"tweak_test\""  -arch armv7     main.cpp -o /Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/main.cpp.262db704.o)
==> Compiling main.cpp (armv7)…
set -o pipefail; (mkdir -p /Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7)
(printf "\e[0;3%im==> \e[1;39m%s…\e[m\n" 3 "Linking tweak tweak_test (armv7)"); set -o pipefail; (xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang++ -L/opt/theos/lib -L/opt/theos/vendor/lib              -F/opt/theos/vendor/lib -framework CydiaSubstrate -dynamiclib -install_name "/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/tweak_test.dylib"  -isysroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.1.sdk" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=__IPHONE_6_0 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -Wl,-segalign,4000 -multiply_defined suppress -arch armv7 -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -O0 -o "/Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/tweak_test.dylib" /Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/main.cpp.262db704.o | (grep -v 'usr/lib/dylib1.o, missing required architecture' || true))
==> Linking tweak tweak_test (armv7)…
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      Mine::poop() in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::allocator<char>::allocator()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::allocator<char>::~allocator()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      Mine::Mine(std::string) in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.262db704.o
      Mine::Mine(std::string) in main.cpp.262db704.o
  "std::string::operator=(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      Mine::Mine(std::string) in main.cpp.262db704.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [/Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/tweak_test.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/ryan/tweaks/tweak_test/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/tweak_test.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [tweak_test.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Note that when building with libstdc++ this builds correctly. I believe that the problem is with either being linked with clang rather than clang++ (doesn't appear to be), or that it is being linked with a different STL than what it had been compiled with (also does not appear to be the case, based on the above verbose output).

If someone could help me with this it would be a year-and-a-half old problem finally put to rest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Somewhere, your settings for libc++ are not being honored. I've never used theos, so I can't help you there.  The key bit here is the name `std::basic_string` - that's a libstdc++ name, since libc++ puts all its symbols in a versioned namespace - specifically, in `std::__1::`  So you're getting libstdc++ headers somehow.